# Setting build.timestamp when publishing from sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, artifactory

Today, my team has a handful of projects which are frequently 'published' for production usage.  We are using JFrog's hosted Artifactory solution to host our binaries, but are running into a problem when project publish both jars and assembly files.

From speaking to someone at JFrog, they said the following.

> 

Artifactory expects the deployment to be in the following order (as done by Maven):

1. jar
2. pom
3. classifiers

I suspect that since you are deploying the files on a different order, Artifactory fails to calculate the unique snapshot.
However, there is a way to make it work:

For each artifact add the ‘build.timestamp’ HTTP matrix param with the current time in milliseconds. Note that all of the artifacts from the same build should have the same timestamp value.

For example:
http://myaccount.artifactoryonline.com/myaccunt/libs-snapshots-local/com/artifact-SNAPSHOT.jar;build.timestamp=1375140480339

Two questions out of this: is SBT really publishing in a different order and if so how do I change the publish url to include this build.timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbt doesn't publish in a defined order.  I don't think there is a way to put a timesamp in the published URL, so the best option is to implement an order in sbt itself.

Previous discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/simple-build-tool/FZqTfpizI-k/discussion
The link there is now at: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/IvyActions.scala#L257

Comment: Is there a feature request list this should be added to or?  Also, how would this work with plugins like sbt-assembly?  It seems like access to defining this ordering will need to be exposed right?

Comment: When publishing, you'd do the main artifact, the pom, then all other artifacts.  I don't think it needs to be configurable.  You can use github.com/sbt/sbt/issues to file the bug or even better, a pull request!

Comment: 6 years later we are still experiencing this issue: some of our sbt builds publish the pom before the jar, causing the build number for the jar to be incremented in Artifactory. In a new SNAPSHOT directory in Artifactory there will be a pom with a -1 suffix for build 1, but no -1 jar will exist, since it's incremented to -2 because it got published after the pom.